# In what game do you play as a knight inside a ghost castle and you're supposed to save a girl

Tags: story-identification, horror, video-games, ghost

You're a knight fighting ghosts (white) in a ghost castle and you need to save a girl I think her hair is white and she is white too (kinda pale I think) It's probably in ps1 or ps2.

Comment: Maximo? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJB0gkbsvWs

Comment: Kuon? https://youtu.be/bjwh60sc3FI

Comment: [This guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question) will help you to improve your question

Comment: Were the graphics 2D or 3D?

Comment: You do not need to change the title; the fact that the question has an accepted answer will indicate it has been solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like it could be [*Ico*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ico) on PS2.

Here's Ico, the player character, and Yorda, the girl you need to rescue. Ico isn't a "knight" exactly, but his horns and headwrap look a little like a helmet:

[image: Screenshot of a cutscene from Ico showing Ico taking Yorda's hand]

Most of the gameplay is about escaping from a huge castle together:

[image: Screenshot of Ico gameplay showing Ico leading Yorda across a bridge in a castle]

The only part that doesn't fit is that the ghosts are black shadows, not white:

[image: Screenshot of Ico gameplay showing Ico fighting off ghosts]

Comment: THANK YOU I'VE BEEN TRYING TO FIND THIS FOR SO LONG

Comment: @Renzo - It would have been easier if you'd told us what kind of game it was :-)

Answer (score 10):

### Super Ghouls 'N Ghosts?

Since you mentioned PlayStation 1. Possibly Super Ghouls 'N Ghosts (aka Cho Makaimura) ?

The woman you save has blue hair (and not white), but she is caucasian and wears a white dress. You do play as a knight in armor and travel through a castle to save the girl.

[image: Knight and woman to be saved]

Here is a gameplay video.